# Select attribute in SQL then checking its value

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, correlated-subquery

I am trying to do a SELECT from a table where an attribute BALANCE should be less than 0. The structure is as follows:

```
SELECT ID_PROJECT FROM PROJECTS WHERE BALANCE < 0;
```

But BALANCE is a derived attribute, the result of:

```
SET BALANCE = (SELECT BALANCE FROM(
[...] here goes the 'selection' (which works fine).
```

The problem is, I don't know how to use the attribute BALANCE selected above in the first SELECT (and I already did a extensive search through google, oracle docs and stack overflow).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us your complete statement Where does this `SET` come from? Plus: "*should be greater than 0*" contradicts your condition `< 0`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right, I have corrected it. The set was a try to create some kind of 'variable' balance, to use in the select, but the subquery method worked. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with a subquery:

```
SELECT ID_PROJECT FROM PROJECTS p1 WHERE (select balance from ...) > 0;
```

In this way you will probably need to use some condition to link `PROJECTS p1` to the table(s) in the nested query, depending on your table structure and your needs

Comment: and be sure that the SubQuery returns **1** result-row & **1** Column always